# how to update image src on success using jquery.form.js

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajaxform

i am using jquery.form.js to ajax submit form and get response.

my php page is set to echo image url like "images/thumbs/071112130957.jpg"

heres my jquery:

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm(
{ 
target: '#preview'
}).submit();
});
```

heres my html form

```
<form action="cropscript.php" id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" /> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload image" />
</form>

<div id="preview" > </div>
<img src = "thumbs/default.jpg" id="thumb_img" />
```

now my question is how do i update the img#thumb_img src after ajaxform success ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was what worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#image').live('change', function()   
    { 
            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({ 
                    target: '#preview',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function (response) {
                                $('#thumb_img').attr('src','images/thumbs/'+response.imgsrc);
                    }
            }).submit();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i use ajaxFrom long time ago but it just pop in my head 
please check document with your version

```
$('#imageform').ajaxForm({
  target : '#preview', 
  complete : function (response) {
     $('#thumb_img').attr('src', response.imgsrc);
  }
});
```

can you test for me if not work let me know

Comment: its not working . how do i generate response.imgsrc ? i did datatype: json and echo json_encode($imgsrc) , is that right ?

Comment: my json is outputing : {"imgsrc":"071112161921.jpg"} how do i get it with jquery ?

Comment: if data is json you can use, if not sure console log response data

$('#thumb_img').attr('src', 'folder/path/' + response.imgsrc);